# Redux return promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux, react-redux

I have a simple function to log out (just for testing) and I would like to inform the user when the action is completed. First that came in mind is to do this with promises.

I tried like this but there is something wrong with it. I don't quite understand how these works. Am I able to do it like this or would there be a better approach?

**Function**

```
logOut = () => {
    this.props.logoutUser().then((passed) => {
        if (passed) {
            alert("You are now logged out!");
        }
    });
};
```

**Logout action**

```
export function logoutUser() {
    return dispatch => {
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            dispatch(logout()).then((response) => {
                return true;
            }).catch((error) => {
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
}

function logout() {
    return {
        type: "LOGOUT"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. Make sure you're using `thunk` middleware and that your thunk returns the Promise.

Comment: I should have thunk working since I'm using it with other actions where 'fetch' is included. This time I would like to use it without 'fetch' :)

Comment: It is the same approach though, because `fetch` returns a Promise as well. If your thunk will *return* the Promise, you will be able to use it in the component (`return new Promise...`).

Comment: As written `logoutUser` is a function that returns a function, and the returned function returns `undefined`.

Comment: Also, you can most likely forget `new Promise(...)` and all that `true/false` business. If, as your code suggests, `dispatch()` returns a promise, simply return it. Back in the caller, successful logout will take you down the promise's success path and failure down the error path.

Comment: Is there a code-example somewhere about this?

Comment: @JackM, do your own research.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 What do you think I have been doing past 58 minutes?

Comment: @JackM, fair comment.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with Logout function

```
export function logoutUser() {
    return dispatch => {
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            dispatch(logout()).then((response) => {
                resolve(true); // changed
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject(error);  // changed
            });
        });
    }
}
```

you have to pass callback function `resolve` for success, and `reject` for fail.
refer this [link](http://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/)

**Update** : and secondly you have to use `thunk` middleware, to work `dispatch` like `Promise` object : [github](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Comment: I still get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" :(

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this with `callback`, like so -

```
logOut = () => {
  this.props.logoutUser(result => {
    if (result.success) {
      alert("You are now logged out!");
      return;
    }

    // Handle error
  });
};

export function logoutUser(callback) {
  logout()
    .then(() => callback({ success: true }))
    .catch(error => callback({ error }));

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: "LOGOUT"
    });
  };
}

function logOut() {
  // log out function that returns a promise
}
```